# publishing Feed via JS SDK properties

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

i have publishing to wall via JS SDK. It works fine, but recently it started doing problems.
Problem is in properties. It doesn't make text hypertext, but shows the link

example:

```
 properties: [{text: "Best fruit", href: "MY APP LINK"}]
```

But in dialog for publishing it shows instead of "Best Fruit" as link to "MY APP LINK" 
it shows "MY APP LINKBest fruit".

There is full code of publishing:

```
function showbox()
{                          
    FB.ui(
    {
        display: 'iframe',
        method: 'feed',
        name: '<?php echo $mes; ?>',
        link: '<?php echo $canvas; ?>',
        caption: '<?php echo $mes; ?>',
        description: ' ',
        properties: <?php echo $_SESSION['properties']; ?>, 
        redirect_uri: '<?php echo $fbconfig['base'];?>'
    });
}
```

How to make it hypertext instead of plain text?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **properties**
>
> A JSON object of key/value pairs which will appear in the stream
>   attachment beneath the description, with each property on its own
>   line. Keys must be strings, and values can be either strings or JSON
>   objects with the keys text and href.

Try putting quotes around `text` and `href`, and remove the square brackets `[` `]` and see if it likes that better.

`properties: {"text": "Best fruit", "href": "MY APP LINK"}`

Comment: Thank you for reply, but it doesn't work. Actualy it worse, when i use your code, it will show in publish dialog this "text: Best fruit href: MY APP LINK"   My solution should be ok, even when i have bad href, facebook throw error, that it is not link to app.

Comment: I played with it in http://developers.facebook.com/tools/console/ and it appears that this is either a documentation bug or a bug with the properties property of the feed FB ui.  You should log a bug at http://developers.facebook.com/bugs and report back here with the bug so others can see it. Thank.

Comment: You were right, it was FB bug. They have repaired it today. Thank you for your time!

Comment: What is the bug number, and can you give me credit for the correct answer please?

Comment: @DMCS: properties: {"text": "Best fruit", "href": "MY APP LINK"} I Tried this but it didnt work for me

Answer (score 1):

I was also facing the same problem. Found something to go on from the [FB Dev Wiki](http://fbdevwiki.com/wiki/FB.ui).

This is what finally worked for me:

```
properties: {" " : {"text":"link text", "href":"http://www.example.com"}},
```

Answer (score 0):

In case the problem still exists...
Your JSON Object with text and href must be wrapped into a key/value pair like this:

`properties: {"test":{"text": "Best fruit", "href": link}}`

Answer (score 0):

It seems

```
properties: {"text":"Somestuff"},
```

outputs "text: Somestuff"

If you only want "Somestuff"

```
properties: {" ":"Somestuff"},
```

will work.